# How to ignore class properties in Swagger

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, swagger

My question is actually simple, is there a way how to ignore property in classes which are already defined by some library or framework (for example, `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`)? I can anotate fields by `@JsonIgnore` in my own classes but si there a way how to do the same in case I can't change theclass itself?

I want this because I am returning `ResponseEntity<Resource>`and Swagger-UI shows me all nested fields of Resource like

```
"url": {
   "authority": "string",
   "content": {},
   "defaultPort": 0,
   "file": "string",
   "host": "string",
   ....
}
```

I am using Springfox with Spring MVC (no Spring Boot), both of them newest versions. Also I don't annotate any fields right now, I leave all the work to Swagger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear if you want to ignore the type itself or do you want to ignore only certain properties on it?

If you want to do the latter is i.e. modify representations of classes you cannot control then [using mixins in jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) should solve your problem. However this is probably not what you want to do. My guess is that you want it to serialize just like how it is supposed to, but you want it to just rendered differently in the swagger service description.

So in your particular case, I would recommend creating an an alternate type rule [as described here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/526#issuecomment-83632352) that substitutes a `ResponseEntity<Resource<T>` with `T` for all T's in your service. The example in the link is for a `Collection<T>`, but it should lead you in the right direction.